# Partitions of Default Install

Tags: partitioning

When the installer automatically sets up partitions during a clean install, what is the outcome?

The question is intended to be general, unless of course other factors play a role in allocating space which would make everyone's setup a bit different.

- HP Pavilion dv7
- InsydeH2O BIOS Setup Utility (v)F.26
- No option for EFI Boot
- Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: Can you maybe [edit] your question to be a bit less general? It would be helpful to know what computer you are trying to install on, what your aim is, and what version of Ubuntu you want. Is this computer EFI capable is a question that needs to be answered first.

Comment: are you ready for a clean install or a dual boot

Comment: I know how to break An EFI boot with a dual boot

Comment: I don't want you to convert your hard disk with an MBR

Comment: of course you need  may be Nvidia or AMD drivers

Answer (score 0):

On a recent installation of Ubuntu 15.10 in a VM, this was my layout after I let it use the entire disk, without LVM:

```
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
vda    253:0    0   15G  0 disk 
├─vda1 253:1    0   14G  0 part /
├─vda2 253:2    0    1K  0 part 
└─vda5 253:5    0 1021M  0 part [SWAP]
```

One huge* ext4 partition, with a swap partition to accompany it.

---

<sub><sup>* for appropriate values of huge</sup></sub>